# Flutter: Set default value from another textformfield to textformfield

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have 3 TextFormField like below:

[image]

And this is the code for 3 TextFormField above:

```
class _ProposalDataInsuranceState extends State<ProposalDataInsurance> {
  
  final _totalPremiController = TextEditingController();
  final _premiPokokController = TextEditingController();
  final _premiTopUpController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _totalPremiController.dispose();
    _premiPokokController.dispose();
    _premiTopUpController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          style:
          textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          controller: _totalPremiController,
          maxLines: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            CurrencyInputFormatter(maxDigits: 16),
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
            hintText: '0',
            hintStyle:
            textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _premiPokokController,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          style: textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          maxLines: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            CurrencyInputFormatter(maxDigits: 16),
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
            hintText: '0',
            hintStyle:
            textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _premiTopUpController,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          style: textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          maxLines: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            CurrencyInputFormatter(maxDigits: 16),
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
            hintText: '0',
            hintStyle:
            textMediumColor(Modular.get<ColorPalettes>().black),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The question is, How to set the default value with validation (`Total Premi` - `Premi Pokok`) for `Premi Topup`?

For example:

1. If I add `50000` in the `Total Premi`, so the value of `Premi Pokok` is still `0` because `Total Premi` - `Premi Pokok` is `50000` - `0` = `0`.
2. If I add `50000` in the `Total Premi` and `40000` in the `Premi Pokok`, so the value of `Premi Pokok` is `10000` because `Total Premi` - `Premi Pokok` is `50000` - `40000` = `10000`.
3. And `Premi Topup` still can edit the value by the user although has the default value with validation from `Total Premi` - `Premi Pokok`.

Comment: You mean you want to set the value of `Premi Topup` on changes of the other two text fields?

Comment: Yes, and I also still can edit the value of `Premi Topup` although has the default value from on changes of the other two text fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set listeners to your text field controllers.

You can do it like the following:

```dart
  ...
  void setPremiTopUpDefault() {
    final totalPremi = int.tryParse(_totalPremiController.text);
    final premiPokok = int.tryParse(_premiPokokController.text);
    if (totalPremi != null && premiPokok != null) {
      _premiTopUpController.text = (totalPremi - premiPokok).toString();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _totalPremiController.addListener(setPremiTopUpDefault);
    _premiPokokController.addListener(setPremiTopUpDefault);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _totalPremiController.removeListener(setPremiTopUpDefault);
    _premiPokokController.removeListener(setPremiTopUpDefault);
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Comment: This does not work, because when the user inputs the value is not changed

Comment: What value is not changed?

Comment: `_premiTopUpController` is not updated when I input the data in `_totalPremiController` and `_premiPokokController`

Comment: Are you sure you've added all the code above correctly? Cause `_premiTopUpController` is updated when inputting data in the two others when I test it on my machine.

Comment: My bad, I need to `replaceAll` first to remove `.` because I add money format. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the on changed of totalpremitopup

use

setState((){

var a=int.parse(totalpremipopup.text)

var b=int.parse(Premipokpok.text)

var c=a-b

premitopup.text=c.toString()

})

Similarly for unchanged in premiokok

use

setState((){

var a=int.parse(totalpremipopup.text)

var b=int.parse(Premipokpok.text)

var c=a-b

premitopup.text=c.toString()

})

I hope this works